# Allow Users to Change their Usernames

Tags: web-applications

Member table carries 3 crucial fields: 

userID - PK
username - unique
eMail - unique

In settings area, users can change their email address as long as the newly input email address doesn't exist in db. I expect many users would request changing their usernames.

It would be great to allow users to change their usernames, but its a risky option and totally unsafe. For example, it could be a great opportunity for a scammer to play his/her game! Then change the username and carry on deceiving members! This is what i'm concerned about. Another problem, if a user is famous and well known then he/she changed the username! A scammer could pick the dropped username and then play his/her game.

Assuming the website is a general classified ads that has some features of forums.

**My current solution is i do the changing for them (assuming there aren't too many requests). However, their previous username will available for others to register. Is this how its done practically/formally?**

Comment: How is it risky/unsafe? It's just as safe as allowing people to change their password.

Comment: Scammer could scam members then change his/her username, there won't be clear evidence for people to be aware of the scammer.

Comment: That very much depends on what kind of website you have. But if people fall for scammers/phishers they usually deserve it anyway. In any case you could send an email on any email/username/password changes to inform the user.

Comment: There are some pages that allow username changes only once in a months and on an account with new username the old username is shown for at least 4 feeks after the change. It's a good solution I think.

Comment: You could store a historical record of usernames and prevent users from ever reusing a username (unless they were the previous owner)

Comment: You can also have old usernames remain unavailable for 30 days or whatever.

Comment: I try to avoid any over killing solutions. "Till Helge Helwig" gave an insight! I could allow the user to change his/her username within 15 days of registration. Afterwords, no manual changing of username is allowed, only through requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to deal with a social or people problem with a technical solution, which never really works for long.

In my opinion, here is your best plan of action:

1. Store a history of usernames
2. Allow people to change usernames no more than once every 30 days
3. The most important step is to fill moderator roles on the forums to ban spammers and "bad people".

You will be unable to prevent spammers and scammers 100%, but you can make their work hard enough that your site is no longer "easy money" and they'll go find some other low-hanging fruit.

Comment: Based on the replies, i came up with the following solution: i could allow user to change his/her username within 15 days of registration. Afterwords, no manual changing of username is allowed, only through requests.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a username change history. This allows you to keep track of the usernames a certain member already had. Maybe these names will be shown to other members too, so that they can compare with known scammer names.
In addition you should not allow any new member to register as a previously registered username even if the user has changed his name. This way ensures that no new member can register with a username known as a scamnmer.

I recommend not to make these changes within database. Build a script for changing the usernames and update the username history.
These features will take time to develop but can assist you a lot.